# Best way to get static files in/out of datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

What's the best way to get files (such as data stored as thousands of text files) from, say, my local machine to a place I can easily load them into a Jupyter notebook? I've installed the `gcloud` tools on my local computer and followed instructions, but `ssh` keeps timing out. If I go to dev console, says I need to change from 'Google managed' to 'self managed' instance to SSH in that way. Does `datalab` need to be Google-managed?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting these into Cloud Storage, and then use the gsutil command to copy over the whole set of files into a bucket.

Once you have that done, check out the storage notebooks for examples of working with files in storage - enumerating, reading/writing, deleting etc.

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream data into a BigQuery table too, and could even do this within your notebook with Table.insert_data, although that may not be ideal if there is a large amount of data. It depends on what you want to do with the data. If it is purely for BQ use then putting it in a BQ table(s) would make sense. If you need to access it from other Google products or easily upload/download it then GCS is more appropriate.